# Issues with manipulating matrix transposed using bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, matrix, transpose

I wrote a bash script that is supposed to calculate the statistical average and median of each columns of an input file. The input file format is shown below. Each number is separated by a tab.

```
1      2      3
3      2      8
3      4      2
```

My approach is to first transpose the matrix, so that rows become columns and vice versa. The transposed matrix is stored in a temporary text file. Then, I calculated the average and median for rows. However, the script gives me the wrong output. First of all, the array that holds the average and median for each column only produces one output. Secondly, the median value calculated is incorrect.

After a bit of code inspection and testing, I discovered that while the transposed matrix did get written to the text file, it is not read correctly by the script. Specifically, each line read only gives one number. Below is my script.

```
 #if column is chosen instead
 89 if [[ $initial == "-c" ]]


 90         then
 91         echo "Calculating column stats"
 92 
 93         #transpose columns to row to make life easier
 94         WORD=$(head -n 1 $filename | wc -w); #counts the number of columns
 95         for((index=1; index<=$WORD; index++)) #loop it over the number of columns
 96             do
 97                 awk '{print $'$index'}' $filename | tr '\n' '   ';echo; #compact way of performing a row-col transposition
 98                 #prints the column as determined by $index, and then translates new-line with a tab
 99             done > tmp.txt
100 
101         array=()
102         averageArray=()
103         medianArray=()
104         sortedArray=()
105 
106         #calculate average and median, just like the one used for rows
107         while read -a cols
108             do
109                 total=0
110                 sum=0
111 
112                 for number in "${cols[@]}" #for every item in the transposed column
113                     do
114                         (( sum += $number )) #the total sum of the numbers in the column
115                         (( total++ )) #the  number of items in the column
116                         array+=( $number )
117                     done
118 
119                 sortedArray=( $( printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n) )
120                 arrayLength=${#sortedArray[@]}
121                 #echo sorted array is $sortedArray      
122                 #based on array length, construct the median array
123                 if [[ $(( arrayLength % 2 )) -eq 0 ]]
124                     then #even
125                         upper=$(( arrayLength / 2 ))
126                         lower=$(( (arrayLength/2) - 1 ))
127                         median=$(( (${sortedArray[lower]} + ${sortedArray[upper]}) / 2  ))
128                         #echo median is $median
129                         medianArray+=$index
130                     else #odd
131                         middle=$(( (arrayLength) / 2 ))
132                         median=${sortedArray[middle]}
133                         #echo median is $median
134                         medianArray+=$index
135                 fi
136                 averageArray+=( $((sum/total)) )  #the final row array of averages that is displayed
137 
138             done < tmp.txt
139 fi
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would strongly suggest trying `awk` for this.

Comment: It's easy: just read the file line by line and store the values in an array. Let's say every row/line contains `W` values. Then, starting from the first element (0) in the array, select those which are at a distance of `W` elements `(0, W, 2W,...)` `(1, W+1, 2W+1, ...)`.

Comment: Firstly, check the `tmp.txt` file contains what it is expected. Secondly, modifying the `awk` command the `tr` command is not needed: `awk '{ printf("%s    ", $'$index')}' $filename; echo;`